# Order of pole(s) in $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+ z^3}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I just want to check that I understand the meaning of the order of poles of a complex variable.

$f(z) = \frac{1}{1+ z^3}$

I believe $f$ has $1$ pole of order $1$ and two poles of order $3$.

Ie. the poles, $-1, e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}, e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}i}$

Is this correct?

Comment: The poles are correct, the orders not.

Comment: You are aware that $g$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z_0$ if and only if $\frac{1}{g}$ has a zero of order $k$ at $z_0$, I suppose?

Comment: If we raise the second or third pole to the power of $3$ they will equal $-1$ and hence will give us a zero in the denominator for $f(z)$. Doesn't that mean they are of order $3$?

Comment: What are the orders of the zeros of $1+z^3$?

Comment: $-1$ is of order $1$. And $e^{\frac{\pi}{3}i}, e^{\frac{5\pi}{3}i}$ are of order $3$.

Comment: No, a polynomial of degree $n > 0$ has $n$ zeros _counting orders_, so the sum of the orders of all zeros is $n$. Here we have a polynomial of degree $3$ with three distinct zeros. It follows that all zeros must be simple.